# Automatic extraction of zip files like in osx

Tags: osx, zip, gzip, file-manager

In Mac OSX if you have downloaded a zip/gz/bz2 file, and you double click it in Finder, then the archive is automatically extracted for you in a subfolder, which I find very nice. I am wondering if there is a similar file manager in the Linux world that has such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can typically create actions within the file managers, I know Nautilus provides this service, so you could create an action that's either custom to .zip files or could be a custom action on a context menu that would allow for this.

Actions are shown how here in this tutorial: [How to Easily Add Custom Right-Click Options to Ubuntu’s File Manager](http://www.howtogeek.com/116807/how-to-easily-add-custom-right-click-options-to-ubuntus-file-manager/).

**NOTE:** The key to this method is making use of a tool called Nautilus-Actions Configuration tool.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I usually use `unp` (from terminal), it unzip any kind of compressed file (zip, gz, bz2, tar.gz, etc) it's pretty nice:

```
$ unp mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
Archive:  mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
   creating: META-INF/
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   creating: META-INF/services/
  inflating: META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
   creating: com/
   ...
```

Comment: I forgot, you can install unp with brew (unp also is on debian/centos/arch repositories)